# Django - Many to One - Cannot Assign Must Be Instance Of

Tags: python, django, many-to-one

I apologize if this is a duplicate post. I have spent days researching and trying to figure this out...but i'm at a dead end. I have a model (Header) that contains all of my order headers, and i need to link that to the (MarketPlace model) market place where they came from. There will only be 2 or 3 lines in the MarketPlace table but every line in Header should be related to one of those lines.

Here is how i am attempting to create a record in the shell: (i may also be doing this wrong):

```
h = Header.objects.filter(retailOrderNum = '185680144')
a = Marketplace(id = None, contactName = 'MP Name',address1='555',address2='666',city = 'Salt Lake City'
 ,state = 'UT',zipCode='84104',country = 'US',phone='555-555-5555',channel=h)
```

I get this error:

Cannot assign "]>": "MarketPlace.channel" must be a "Header" instance.

Here are my models:

```
class Header(models.Model):
    retailOrderNum = models.CharField(max_length=50,primary_key = True)
    orderNum = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    channel = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    orderDate = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    contactName = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    address1 = models.CharField(max_length=1500)
    address2 = models.CharField(max_length=1500, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length =100)
    state =models.CharField(max_length =100)
    zipCode =models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length =100)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length =100,null=True)
    #shippingSpecifications =models.CharField(max_length =100)
    shippingCode = models.CharField(max_length =100)
    orderShippedDate = models.DateTimeField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.retailOrderNum


class Line(models.Model):
    retailOrderNum =models.ForeignKey(Header, on_delete=models.CASCADE,db_column='retailOrderNum')
    item = models.CharField(max_length =100)
    lineNo = models.IntegerField()
    lineId = models.CharField(max_length =100)
    itemId = models.CharField(max_length =100)
    qty = models.IntegerField()
    retail = models.FloatField()
    revenue = models.FloatField()
    shipping = models.FloatField()
    lineStatus = models.CharField(max_length =100)
    qtyShipped = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    trackingNumber = models.CharField(max_length =500,null=True)
    shipCarrier = models.CharField(max_length =100,null=True)
    shippedDate = models.DateTimeField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.item



class MarketPlace(models.Model):
    channel = models.ForeignKey(Header)
    contactName = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    address1 = models.CharField(max_length=1500)
    address2 = models.CharField(max_length=1500, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length =100)
    state =models.CharField(max_length =100)
    zipCode =models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length =100)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length =100,null=True)
```

Comment: Looks like you've passed a queryset rather than a model to me. Try changing `Header.objects.filter` to `Header.objects.get` maybe?

Comment: @shadow got it right. You can also try `Header.objects.filter(...).first()` if multiple results is a probability.

Comment: If someone else thinks so to, guess I'll promote this to an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code returns a queryset:

```
h = Header.objects.filter(retailOrderNum='185680144')
```

You need to provide just one model to the channel argument (it says in the traceback that `"MarketPlace.channel" must be a "Header" instance`) - so you should use this instead;

```
h = Header.objects.get(retailOrderNum='185680144')
```